# Postgres fails when creating enum

Tags: postgresql

I have a following enum that I want to create:

```
CREATE TYPE "test" AS ENUM('0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '25', '11', '12', '14', '16', '20', '18', '17', '22', '13', '23', '24', '28', '27', '26', '29', '32', '19', '31', '30', '33', '35', '34', '1', '38', '36', '37', '40', '39', '41', '43', '42', '1', '45', '46', '15', '44', '10', '1', '47', '48', '49', '21', '1', '50', '51', '253', '254', '255');
```

When I try to execute that code, I get:

```
SQL Error [23505]: ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "pg_enum_typid_label_index"
  Detail: Key (enumtypid, enumlabel)=(33404, 1) already exists.
```

I honestly don't understand what the issue is. The number of items should be well below any limit for enums, but if I reduce it to certain number of items, it actually works. What is the problem here?

---

Version of Postgres used is 9.6.20.

Comment: You have the value `'1'` in your list twice.  There may be other duplicates, as well, but I confirmed `'1'` after both `'0'` and `'42'`.

Comment: You have at least `1` twice in there.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - there are only some values in there. These are country codes for digital tachographs as specified by EU legislation, not really a bunch of random numbers.

Comment: @MikeOrganek - whelp, I was given poor data, it seems. Post that as an answer please so that I can give you credit. Still, what an unhelpful error message...

Comment: @Davor: the error message seems fine (though not perfect) too me. It does point out there's a duplicate value somewhere, with the corresponding label (though the value `1` does not really stand out as much as `SOME_ACTUAL_ENUM_VALUE` would).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your enum definition contains duplicate values.

If you remove all those duplicate '1' values, it will work:

```
CREATE TYPE "test" AS ENUM('0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '25', '11', '12', '14', '16', '20', '18', '17', '22', '13', '23', '24', '28', '27', '26', '29', '32', '19', '31', '30', '33', '35', '34', '38', '36', '37', '40', '39', '41', '43', '42', '45', '46', '15', '44', '10', '47', '48', '49', '21', '50', '51', '253', '254', '255');
```